# Difference between addressing and answering a question

Tags: meaning

"To address the question",
"To answer the question".
What's the difference?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To **address** a question is to **deal with** a question, not necessarily to answer it.

To **answer** a question is to provide the information requested in the question.

See [this link](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/question).

People who say **address the question** when they mean **answer the question** are being pretentious.

Answer (score 4):

You can address a question without answering it. If, for example, allegations are made against a person and a central question comes up, then the person can address the question without actually answering it.

Also, if we can't answer a questions, it doesn't necessarily mean that we can't say something that might be useful about the topic in question. So we address the question.